# How to check if a database table exists in TYPO3 using doctrine?

Tags: doctrine, typo3

Although the TYPO3 core takes good care of having all tables, there might be situations where you need to check if a table exists.
The situation at hand is an Update Wizard which interacts with another extension, where the other extension has a migration changing table names.

So: how to check if a table exists in current TYPO3, thus using doctrine and possibly even multiple database connections

Answer (score 3):

At least for 10LTS, 11LTS and (as of now probably 12LTS too)

```
return GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)
        ->getConnectionForTable($tablename)
        ->getSchemaManager()
        ->tablesExist([$tablename]);
```

This works because if no connection for the table is defined because the table doesn't exist, still the default connection is used and a check can be done there.